# find_no_duplicates raise KeyError in Python requests library

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

This piece of code worked before (when I developed it in May 2015, so maybe my Python/Requests version is causing the issue). I am currently on `requests version: 2.9.1` I have getting the following error in my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./add.py", line 98, in <module>
    'SESSID':term.cookies['SESSID'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 276, in __getitem__
    return self._find_no_duplicates(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 331, in _find_no_duplicates
    raise KeyError('name=%r, domain=%r, path=%r' % (name, domain, path))
KeyError: "name='SESSID', domain=None, path=None"
```

Line 98 in `add.py` refers to the following:

```
# Grab the Add/Drop Class page cookies                                
ad_cookie = {                                                         
    'SESSID':term.cookies['SESSID'],                                  
    'IDMSESSID':username                                              
}
```

Just to make sure that the particular cookie in that page was not removed or missing, I checked the cURL for when I hit that page, and surely enough, both `SESSID` and `IDMSESSID` were in that cURL request.

Wondering what the issue is?

EDIT:

I've added some more code:

```
username = info['username']                                            
password = info['password']                                            
term_in = info['term_in']                                              

login_url="https://school.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fschool.edu%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin"

# Fake random user agent generator                                     
ua = UserAgent()                                                       

# Persist a session                                                    
with requests.Session() as s:                                          

    # Call this URL to get our initial hidden parameter variables      
    # In particular, the `lt` variable changes every time [I'm not     
    # sure how often, but it's necessary every time you login]         
    page = s.get('https://school.edu/web/university')              

    # Convert page to string for easy scraping                         
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)                                  

    # Grab our unique variables from these particular XPaths           
    # Yes, the XPaths are a MESS, but that's because School's websites 
    # are a mess.                                                      
    lt = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fm1"]/div[4]/input[1]/@value')           
    execution = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fm1"]/div[4]/input[2]/@value')    
    eventId = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fm1"]/div[4]/input[3]/@value')      
    submit = tree.xpath('//*[@id="fm1"]/div[4]/input[4]/@value') 

    l_payload = {                                                      
        'username':username,                                           
        'password':password,                                           
        'lt':lt,                                                       
        'execution':execution,                                         
        '_eventId':eventId,                                            
        'submit':submit                                                
    }                                                                  

    # Login page cookies                                               
    l_cookies = {                                                      
        'JSESSIONID':page.cookies['JSESSIONID'],                       
        'IDMSESSID':username                                           
    }                                                                  

    # Login page headers with a fake user-agent generator              
    l_headers = {                                                      
        "Referer":"https://login.school.edu/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fschool.edu%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin",
        "User-Agent":ua.random                                         
    }                                                                  

    # Now we login to School Connect, School's single-sign-o           
    # for all its web apps like School Learn, School One, etc          
    # For more info in this:                                           
    # https://www.school.edu/irt/help/a-z/schoolConnect/               
    s.post(                                                            
        login_url,                                                     
        data = l_payload,                                              
        cookies = l_cookies,                                           
        headers = l_headers,                                           
        allow_redirects = True                                         
    )                                                                  

    # Go to the "Add/Drop Class" link within School One                
    # to grab the SESSID cookie which will allow us to                 
    # add and/or drop classes                                          
    term = s.get('https://bannersso.school.edu/ssomanager/c/SSB?pkg=bwszkfrag.P_DisplayFinResponsibility%3Fi_url%3Dbwskfreg.P_AltPin')

    #print html.fromstring(term.text)                                  
    #sys.exit(0)                                                       

    # Grab the Add/Drop Class page cookies                             
    ad_cookie = {                                                      
        'SESSID':term.cookies['SESSID'],                               
        'IDMSESSID':username                                           
    }
```

EDIT 2:

I printed out `term.headers` and the following is the result:

```
{'content-length': '8624', 'content-language': 'en', 'set-cookie': 'TESTID=set, SESSID=;expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 08:00:00 GMT, PROXY_HASH=;expires=Mon, 01-Jan-1990 08:00:00 GMT', 'keep-alive': 'timeout=5, max=100', 'server': 'Oracle-Application-Server-11g', 'connection': 'Keep-Alive', 'date': 'Thu, 31 Mar 2016 16:00:30 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

It seems like there are no cookies at all.

Comment: What is `term` and what does it contain? Can you print its value? `KeyError` is being raised because it seems `SESSID` is not present in the `cookies`. Can you show the rest of the code where you are sending the request and getting the response in `term` (<em>I assume</em>).

Comment: Ok - nevermind. I can use `term.cookies.get_dict()`. It seems it is indeed empty. What was returned was `{}`. That's really weird, as this piece of code worked last year. I have attached the complete code of the script.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage *"How do I print all the items within term.cookies?"* Check [this](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: @jDo I figured it out, thanks =). `term.cookies.get_dict()` returned `{}` which indicates it is indeed empty. That's really weird, as this script worked (albeit last year). I also checked that request in my Chrome Dev Tools and both `SESSID` and `JDMSESSID` exists. So maybe my POST request before the `s.get()` is the issue...

Comment: I feel stupid. Turns out my username and password were incorrect, hence why I wasn't authenticated, and why I didn't have my sessions. Oh boy.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage d'oh! :D