# Instagram bot (python) closes automatically with an error message. Used to work perfectly before my Windows update

Tags: python, crash, instagram, bots

The Instagram (python) bot that I have, used to work like a charm. There were no crashes or any errors/problems.

However, one day my Windows decided to start an auto update. And... After that my bot stopped working. Now, when I try to open it, it shows a quick error message and closes immediately (as soon as I open it).

The update happened a few months ago so getting back to the previous Windows version isn't possible.

The bot is updated and it works great on a different PC. For some reasons it just doesn't want to work on my computer.

You can see the error message below:

[image: The error message given when running the bot]

Comment: A quick search on Google came up with these two: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/3072 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324361/find-no-duplicates-raise-keyerror-in-python-requests-library. please investigate them as this is hard to debug with only the info you gave.

Comment: Can you show some code? instabot.py, lines 212, 263 and associated